# Checklist for thread-safe java on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, thread-safety

My java appengine project does not keep any state between requests except for the following uses of Memcache:

- Objectify uses memcache to cache datastore gets
- I use memcache as a way to batch cleanup tasks after multiple requests (e.g. `if (the memcache doesn't think a cleanup task is already running) schedule another cleanup task`).

I have no global / static references to any objects, except:

- The current authenticated user is kept in a `static ThreadLocal<User>` object.  This means each request will get its own copy of a User, right?
- I have a class that handles all data manipulation, and an instance is kept as a sort of global variable in a `static DataCoordinator` object.

What do I need to look out for to make my code thread-safe?  Do I need to throw a `synchronized` keyword into every method declaration in my `DataCoordinator` implementation, since multiple threads could access it?  Is it true that the `ThreadLocal<User>` object will always make a separate `User` object for each thread, so that each request will be authenticated separately?

I'm a total newbie to thread-safe thinking.  What should I read?

Thanks for any help, and sorry for the lack of specificity.

Comment: Do you have any singlton classes, where you always get a reference to the same instance via a .getInstance()? If so, multiple parallel requests executed in different threads inside the same VM/instance could be getting a reference to the same object....and then class in their use of it or modification of instance variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing you should be aware of is that app engine can replicate your application on multiple servers. That means your static variables will be unique only on one server. Thus your `DataCoordinator` will coordinate only the data access on a single server. So if you need common data to all servers running your app you should always use the data store for that (or gae HTTP session mechanism in some cases).

Regarding thread safety of `DataCoordinator`: You only need to synchronize methods of this coordinator if these methods are not implemented in a thread safe manner. For example you do not need to synchronize any methods that don't access any instance/static data but merely fetch data from the datastore. If methods access common instance/static data that is mutable (is also concurrently written) you can synchronize on a special monitor for the accessed data in most cases instead of synchronizing on the whole coordinator.

Regarding your `ThreadLocal` used to store auth token: You can do that (I do that for example for user authentication in gae for GWT request factory requests) and yes, every thread will have it's own variable value as long as you set it for that thread. Meaning it is best to make sure that the variable is set for each thread and it is adviceable to use a `try`-`finally`-block after setting it that eventually removes the authentication data after use. Why? Worst thing that could happen otherwise would be that a thread that belongs to user B's request still has an auth token of user A. That is because threads used in application server are usually pooled between requests instead of cleand up and recreated.

I cannot say anything about memcache since I have not used it.

Generally you have to be aware that any web requests (servlet/JSP/...) can be handled concurrently by the server. So any mutable shared resources that are accessed by those threads should be either synchronized or implemented in a thread safe manner.

Maybe http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ is a good starting point to read into it.

Comment: I don't need the datacoordinator to be the same for all threads, I just need it to not mess anything up when it happens to be accessed by two competing threads. Thanks for the answer - I'll look at this tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

If you have singleton classes, then only ONE instance will be created/used by your code per VM/Instance created.

A reference to this singleton can be fetched from:
- two sequential requests made one after another that are served by the same instance (depends on your settings how long they stay around, or if a reserved instance is running)
- two parallel requests running in separate threads on the same instance IF you have threadsafe set to true.

I have written and tested code to confirm this to myself, and deployed and tested. If code in one requests uses the singleton to modify one of its member variables, then it is modified for the other request running in parallel.

All logical really, once you figure out the lifetime of a VM and how many threads (only 1, or many) are used to serve incoming requests.

Also, System variables can be modified in code in one request and read in another...a second way two parallel requests/threads can interact.

See more details on this in my blog post on multi-threading in GAE/J here:
http://devcon5.blogspot.com/2012/09/threadsafe-in-appengine-gaej.html